# Drupal 8 does not create path alias' valid for all languages

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I have a Drupal 8 multi lingual site setup using the module [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) to generate path alias for taxonomy terms. The alias are created form the name of the tags, which are not translated but rather are in all languages the same. So I want all those alias be valid  for all languages.
The settings page of the module Pathauto lets me either leaving all languages unselected or choose specific languages for which the created path should be valid for. But unfortunately the pathes are created only for English and do not work if a user has a different language selected.

Is that a bug, or am I not doing it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's currently not supported.

Partially blocked by core, which also doesn't allow to create language-neutral aliases while editing nodes and then also wouldn't show them anymore. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2511968 and https://www.drupal.org/node/2689459. Once those are resolved, pathauto could follow those definitions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. But this is bad news. That means you can use alias on English sites only. Or is there any work around?

Comment: You could implement some custom code to generate the aliases. And you could test my patch in the first issue, it should be ready to be committed and was already RTBC once.